# Android specific animations Xamarin.Forms - Splash screen

Tags: android, xml, animation, xamarin.forms

I have made a splash screen for Android by implementing a new Activity. It points to a xml theme that includes android specific code (@style/Splash). That points to a drawable xml of splash.

My question is, If we can do these kinds of platform specific implementations, can we also create animations using this same pattern? I have placed an example of code from the android dev website to give you an idea of what I am trying to include. If yes, what would this code look like in XF.Android and how can we reference it?

SplashActivity.cs

```
    [Activity(Label = "SplashActivity", Theme = "@style/Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        }
    }
```

style/Splash

```
  <style name="Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
  </style>
```

drawable/splash

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="#03045E"/>
  </item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:src="@drawable/logo1"
      android:tileMode="disabled"
      android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Example anim that I want to include hyperspace_jump.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="700" />
    <set
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:startOffset="700">
        <scale
            android:fromXScale="1.4"
            android:toXScale="0.0"
            android:fromYScale="0.6"
            android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="400" />
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="-45"
            android:toYScale="0.0"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create a `Anim` folder and put the `hyperspace_jump.xml` file in it.**

**2. Create the layouts.**

SplashScreen Layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
p1:minWidth="25px"
p1:minHeight="25px"
p1:layout_width="match_parent"
p1:layout_height="match_parent"
p1:background="@android:color/white"
p1:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">

<ImageView
    p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    p1:id="@+id/imageView"
    p1:layout_centerVertical="true"
    p1:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    p1:src="@drawable/a01" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<TextView
    android:text="Main Activity Started"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**3. Code Behind:**

SplashScreenActivity:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
{
    ImageView imageView;
    Animation view_animation;
    TextView textview;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        RequestWindowFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
        imageView = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageView);
        
        view_animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this,Resource.Animation.hyperspace_jump);
         
        imageView.StartAnimation(view_animation);
        view_animation.AnimationEnd += Rotate_AnimationEnd;
        
    }

    private void Rotate_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
        Finish();
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome to MainActivity", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

**4. Screenshot:**

[image]

You could download from the GitHub for reference. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/SplashScreenDemo