# White screen after splash screen

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, splash-screen

When I put the splash screen in my app, then a white screen appears and then the main screen.

I realized that it is the white screen  the background my app that shows it for two seconds and then enters the main screen.

I wanted to know if there is a way to delete this page or make it last zero second?

Thanks to those who answer me!

this  code is my  splash screen:

```
[Activity(Label = "myapp", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
        }


        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            Task splashwork = new Task(async () => { await Task.Delay(3000); });
            splashwork.ContinueWith(h =>
            {
                StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));

                TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
            });
            splashwork.Start();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two activities. One activity is used to show the splash screen and the other used to show the mian activity.

[image]

You could check the sample code i done before. [Android specific animations Xamarin.Forms - Splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583462/android-specific-animations-xamarin-forms-splash-screen)

**Updated:**

Create a Splash Screen. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

Create a splash_screen.xml in drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
   <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
 </item>
  <item>
  <bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Add specifial color in Resources/values/colors.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  ...
  <color name="splash_background">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Create a Theme in Resources/values/styles.xml

```
 <style name="Theme_SplashScreen" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

Load the splash screen in Activity_SplashScreen activity.

```
 [Activity(Label = "Activity_SplashScreen", Theme = "@style/Theme_SplashScreen", MainLauncher = true)]
public class Activity_SplashScreen : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        Task startupWork = new Task(() => { SimulateStartup(); });
        startupWork.Start();
    }
    // Simulates background work that happens behind the splash screen
    async void SimulateStartup()
    {             
        await Task.Delay(3000); // Simulate a bit of startup work.            
        StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(Activity_Screen)));
    }
}
```

Activity_Screen activity:

```
 [Activity(Label = "Activity_Screen")]
public class Activity_Screen : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout_Screen);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome to MainActivity", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. But I do not see your code. Your link is incorrect. If you can show me your code.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have updated the link. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you.
I do not have animation in Splash screen. I only have one image with a black background, and I have two pages, one for the splash screen and one for the main activity. However, if you can guide me, thank you. Or if you give me a code, thank you.

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check the code.

Comment: @hoh This comment maybe for another case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173507/justify-text-without-custom-render/65177212?noredirect=1#comment115264627_65177212 I need the webview to load the htnl which arranges the ends of the texts. For now, it was the best solution i could provide.

Comment: In my VS in Activity_Screen  it do not find the layout_Screen. How do I solve this problem? @Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: `layout_Screen` is a layout which starts after splash screen. You could create a new layout or just use the Mian layout.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! @  Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: Can this solution be applicable in .NET Maui? Just curious though.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue of Xamarin Forms targeting Android 10 while using `NavigationPage` as a wrapper of the main page, it is still not fixed by XF development team you can follow it progress/status on [[Bug] White Screen in Android when using NavigationPage](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11993)

Comment: Is there no way to fix it?

Comment: You can try to change your application structure and make it based on [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) and try maybe if it is not affected by this problem, but I don't think so.. The work load depends on your app size.

Comment: Thanks for comment!

Comment: as a final question, if I use to Shell,  Will the problem be solved?

Comment: I really don't know, as I have said you can try (just an opinion I don't think it is not affected by this problem) I totally agree that it can be annoying hope they will solve soon.

Answer (score 0):

your task delay says "3000" which means it'll take 3 seconds, lower down to "1000" and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no the solution in your case but in my case it works.

I just created a clean Xamarin app an added a SplashScreen to it using the steps from Microsoft web site.

[Xamarin SplashScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen)

It works but a black screen appears after splash screen and before app load (sometimes it takes several seconds in this).

Following the answered question in MSDN
[Xamarin Forms 10 seconds black screen after Splash Screen](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4dc3c484-0fb9-4ed4-91ee-8d814e627dd2/xamarin-forms-10-seconds-black-screen-after-splash-screen?forum=xamarinforms)

The solution was to add  `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` to the style of the main activity theme. Then my `style.xml` file ends like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">    
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> <!--Add this line-->
  </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: This solve my problem, it removes the black screen after splash screen.