# justify text without custom render

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I wanted to know if there is no way other than custom rendering to arrange the ends of the texts in xamarinforms?

Because the modification does not support Android 7 and below.

Thanks to those who respond!

This code is related to my CustomRendering , which in Android 7, my app crashes:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRender))]

namespace Liko.Droid
{

    public class CustomLabelRender : LabelRenderer
    {
        public CustomLabelRender(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {

            base.OnElementChanged(e);


            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.JustificationMode = JustificationMode.InterWord;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 7.0, it do not support `JustificationMode`. `JustificationMode` is added in API level 26.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#justificationMode

The customrenderer could justify text in Android 7.0 with ViewRenderer.

Custom control:

```
 public class JustifiedLabel : Label
{
}
```

Csutom renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(JustifiedLabel), typeof(JustifiedLabelRenderer))]
```

namespace Test.Droid
{
public class JustifiedLabelRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
public JustifiedLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{

```
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        //if we have a new forms element, we want to update text with font style (as specified in forms-pcl) on native control
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                //register webview as native control
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Context);
                webView.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
                webView.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;

                webView.LoadData("<html><body>&nbsp;</body></html>", "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
                SetNativeControl(webView);
            }

            //if we have a new forms element, we want to update text with font style (as specified in forms-pcl) on native control
            UpdateTextOnControl();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        //if there is change in text or font-style, trigger update to redraw control
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Label.Text)
           || e.PropertyName == nameof(Label.FontFamily)
           || e.PropertyName == nameof(Label.FontSize)
           || e.PropertyName == nameof(Label.TextColor)
           || e.PropertyName == nameof(Label.FontAttributes))
        {
            UpdateTextOnControl();
        }
    }

    void UpdateTextOnControl()
    {
        var webView = Control as Android.Webkit.WebView;
        var formsLabel = Element as Label;

        // create css style from font-style as specified
        var cssStyle = $"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; color: {ToHexColor(formsLabel.TextColor)}; background-color: {ToHexColor(formsLabel.BackgroundColor)}; font-family: {formsLabel.FontFamily}; font-size: {formsLabel.FontSize}; font-weight: {formsLabel.FontAttributes}";

        // apply that to text 
        var strData =
            $"<html><body style=\"{cssStyle}\">{formsLabel?.Text}</body></html>";

        // and, refresh webview
        webView.LoadData(strData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
        webView.Reload();
    }

    // helper method to convert forms-color to css-color
    string ToHexColor(Color color)
    {
        var red = (int)(color.R * 255);
        var green = (int)(color.G * 255);
        var blue = (int)(color.B * 255);
        var alpha = (int)(color.A * 255);
        var hex = $"#{red:X2}{green:X2}{blue:X2}";

        return hex;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 <StackLayout Margin="20">
        <Entry x:Name="InputEntry" />

        <Label
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            BackgroundColor="Navy"
            FontSize="15"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Normal Text Label"
            TextColor="White" />
        <Label
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="20"
            Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference InputEntry}}" />

        <Label
            Margin="0,10,0,0"
            BackgroundColor="Navy"
            FontSize="15"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="Justified Text Label"
            TextColor="White" />
        <local:JustifiedLabel
            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="20"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference InputEntry}}"
            TextColor="Green"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />

    </StackLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Updated:**

```
 public class JustifiedLabelRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    Context _context;
    Android.Webkit.WebView webView;
    public JustifiedLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        //if we have a new forms element, we want to update text with font style (as specified in forms-pcl) on native control
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (Control == null)
            {
                //register webview as native control
                webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
                webView.VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false;
                webView.HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;

                var formsLabel = Element as Label;

                // create css style from font-style as specified
                var cssStyle = $"margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; color: {ToHexColor(formsLabel.TextColor)}; background-color: {ToHexColor(formsLabel.BackgroundColor)}; font-family: {formsLabel.FontFamily}; font-size: {formsLabel.FontSize}; font-weight: {formsLabel.FontAttributes}";
                
                // apply that to text 
                var strData = $"<html><body style=\"{cssStyle}\">{formsLabel?.Text}</body></html>";

                webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("", strData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8", "");

                SetNativeControl(webView);

            }

        }
 string ToHexColor(Color color)
    {
        var red = (int)(color.R * 255);
        var green = (int)(color.G * 255);
        var blue = (int)(color.B * 255);
        var alpha = (int)(color.A * 255);
        var hex = $"#{red:X2}{green:X2}{blue:X2}";

        return hex;
    }
    }
```

xaml:

```
   <local:JustifiedLabel
            BackgroundColor="Yellow"
            FontAttributes="Bold"
            FontSize="20"
            WidthRequest="500"
            HeightRequest="500"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="I wanted to know if there is no way other than custom rendering to arrange the ends of the texts in xamarinforms? Because the modification does not support Android 7 and below. Thanks to those who respond! This code is related to my CustomRendering , which in Android 7, my app crashes:"
            TextColor="Green"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But when I use your code, it does not show the text. I'm using a content page that has a label and image.

Comment: I have updated my reply. Please check it.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for Answer, my VS not found ToHexColor . How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I deleted Tohexcolor and the error was fixed, but it still does not show the text. Should I use Web View on the content page to display the text? Where do you think the problem is?

Comment: I missed to add the xaml in the updated code. It may be necessary to set the WidthRequest and HeightRequest properties of the WebView to see the HTML content. Please check the xaml and screenshot for updated.

Comment: I apologize . Now I put the question in the right place. that was my fault.  As a final question, should I use Web View? Or is it not necessary to use Web View?@Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: For now, i used the webview to load the html which arranges the ends of the texts. It is the best suggestion i could provided now.

Comment: @hoh Any update for this case? Have you solved this issue?

Comment: No, if I use Web View, will there be no problem displaying the page? My app is offline. My page is a content page where there is a Stack Layout with an image and a label. @Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: It's okay. Webview is used to load the html. It works well on offline mode.

Comment: @hoh Any update? Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Not yet. Unfortunately I was busy. Is WebView suitable for displaying descriptions offline?@Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: There is no trace of WebView in your Xaml code, please update it too!@Wendy Zang - MSFT

Comment: @hoh I use the custom renderer to assign the webview to the label. The webview would not show anything in xaml. I have tested. It works well for offline. The xaml code i provided is right.

Answer (score 0):

In general you may use Effects, but that won't make any significant difference.

The code above is not Xamarin.Forms, but rather Xamarin.Android. As such to code it well you must learn Android as Xamarin.Android is just mapped general Android Java APIs to .NET APIs.

Speaking of your problem you need to check for the version of Android before executing the code that is problematic. But your general problem is that you don't know Android, so you'll have many problems like this unless you learn it.