# Display two icons on Android. How to reduce the number of icons to one

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm developing with Xamarin.
When I created a splash screen for Android, I encountered a problem.
When I build it on a real device, two icons are displayed on the phone.
When I uninstall one of them, both are deleted.

[image]

What does this mean?
Is there something wrong with my settings?
Please let me know how to fix it.
Thank you very much.
The steps I took are as follows

SplashScreen
The splash screen will be implemented in Android.
(1) Add SplashActivity to Droid.
(2) Change the attribute of MainActivity from MainTheme to SplashTheme.

```
    [Activity(Label = "RG2022", 
        Icon = "@mipmap/icon",
        //Theme = "@style/MainTheme", //comment out
        Theme = "@style/SplashTheme", //change to this
```

(3)Add MainActivity Oncreate

```
    Window.RequestFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
    SetTheme(Resource.Style.MainTheme);
```

(4)Add RG2022\RG2022\RG2022.Android\Resources\drawable\splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
      <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    </shape>
  </item>
    <item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:tileMode="disabled"
        android:gravity="center"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

(5)Add RG2022\RG2022\RG2022.Android\Resources\values\styles.xml

```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent ="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>  
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
```

(6)Add Splash.png at drowable
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.rg2022" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:label="RG2022"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

https://github.com/misakikaoru/SG2022

Comment: You can expose multiple activities with an own icon on Android. But I am not sure how this feature is activated using Xamarin as your AndroidManifest.xml looks way too empty (no activity at all defined).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create two activities. One is the splash screen activity and the other is the normal activity.

SplashScreenActivity:

```
public class SplashScreenActivity : Activity
{
    ImageView imageView;
    Animation view_animation;
    TextView textview;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        RequestWindowFeature(Android.Views.WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
        imageView = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageView);
        
        view_animation = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this,Resource.Animation.hyperspace_jump);
         
        imageView.StartAnimation(view_animation);
        view_animation.AnimationEnd += Rotate_AnimationEnd;
        
    }

    private void Rotate_AnimationEnd(object sender, Animation.AnimationEndEventArgs e)
    {
        Finish();
        StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome to MainActivity", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
```

For more details, you could refer to the thread i done before.
[Android specific animations Xamarin.Forms - Splash screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583462/android-specific-animations-xamarin-forms-splash-screen/63592865#63592865)

Comment: Thank you answer.
My current issue is that when I build it on the actual device, it displays two icons on my phone.
I am looking for a way to reduce the number of icons to one.

Comment: For this, i did not display two icons. Could you provide more details about this? Maybe i misunderstand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks wendy! you can try this project at https://github.com/misakikaoru/SG2022 . Please try it.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue. Because that you set the `MainLauncher=true` twice. Only set it in SplashActivity and delete it in MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks Wendy! I comment out MainLauncher=true in MainActivity. Then Icon became one!